# ACF adding CPT fields to header

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type called 'Projects' and I have added flexible field content to my single-projects.php. I'm trying to add a hero image for each project that sits in the main header.php as I want my hero image to sit behind the navigation. I have everything working but my hero image is displaying on CPT archive pages and CPT single pages but I just want to show the hero image on each project page.

in my header.php file I have:

```
<?php

  // check if the flexible content field has rows of data
  if( have_rows('project_flexible') ):

  // loop through the rows of data
  while ( have_rows('project_flexible') ) : the_row();

    if( get_row_layout() == 'project_hero_image'):
      $hero_image = get_sub_field('image'); ?>

    <div class="hero-image"><img src="<?php echo $hero_image; ?>">
    </div>

    <?php
      endif;
      endwhile;

      else :
       // no layouts found
      endif;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could try this to only display on single page:

```
<?php

// check if the flexible content field has rows of data
if( have_rows('project_flexible') ):

// loop through the rows of data
while ( have_rows('project_flexible') ) : the_row();

if( get_row_layout() == 'project_hero_image'):
  $hero_image = get_sub_field('image'); ?>

// Added this if statement
<?php if(is_single()){ ?>
  <div class="hero-image"><img src="<?php echo $hero_image; ?>"></div>
<?php } ?>

<?php
  endif;
  endwhile;

  else :
   // no layouts found
  endif;
?>
```